# Unity building for iOS - build succeeds but nothing happens

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a Unity app which successfully builds for iOS with no errors in the console, but nothing happens. No errors, and nothing appears on the connected iPad/iPhone.
I have XCode installed and I created an Apple ID following the [Unity Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-GettingStarted.html), but there's no other special steps listed there to follow.

*How do I run my development iOS build on a connected device?*

Comment: You asked a question and instantly answered it by yourself?

Comment: Yeah, it's a built-in StackExchange feature labelled "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style" style. When there's no clear answer available online and you've spent time working something out it's a good way to help the next guy who searches for the same question as you. I'm unsure why there's downvotes, I couldn't find any duplicate, other Unity/XCode Qs are found on StackOverflow (instead of eg GameDev/AskDifferent), and the steps below seem valid/required to me.. although I hope someone else answers with a better (ie. less manual) solution, which I would then accept.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few extra steps you need to take to run your app:

- After the build, open the XCode project that was generated.
- Select the "Unity-iPhone" root of the project, then select the "Signing & Capabilities" tab.
- Enable "Automatically manage signing"
- Under "Team", add an account, sign in with your Apple ID, and then select it in the dropdown.
- Click the Play button to build and run your project to your device.
- On your iPhone/iPad, open Settings > General > Device Management and trust the app.
- It should now run.

Tested with Mac 11.2.3 (Big Sur), iOS 14.4, XCode 12.4, and Unity 2019.4 LTS.